# How to make generic this function in C++ (i.e., template based)

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I use gcc version 4.6.3. I want to implement a function to allocate 2-dimensional matrices and initialize them. I used the following code, but I want a template based (or generic) one. I want a generic function to handle bool, float, and double at the same time (the procedure is similar in all cases). Could you please help me, or introduce me a better way to allocate a 2d matrix.

```
void doubleAlloc2D(double ** &t, int r, int c,double initialValue=0)
{
    t=new double*[r];
    if (!t)
    {
        if (DETAILS) std::printf  ("Not enough memory.(code: 461546596551)\n");
        getchar();
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        t[i] = new double[c];
        if (!t[i])
        {
            if (DETAILS) std::printf  ("Not enough memory.(code: 461651651)\n");
            getchar();
            exit(-1);
        }
        for (int j=0;j<c;j++)
            t[i][j] = initialValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's supposed to be generic? Any type instead of just `double`?

Comment: Use `std::vector`. then it’s automatically generic (the function becomes redundant).

Comment: new throws when it's out of memory, it doesn't return null. Unless you're on an ancient compiler, in which case I would stay away from templates.

Comment: `template <typename T> std::vector<std::vector<T>> alloc2D(int r, int c, T initialValue = T()) { return std::vector<std::vector<T>>(r, std::vector<T>(c, initialValue)); }` OMG C++ code can be so short!

Comment: yes, simply int and float, or may be some variants of them

Comment: please answer me below, I cannot read it correctly.

Comment: Love those error codes !

Comment: @remo You can simply copy-paste the C++ one-liner into your favourity text editor and indent it properly. If you're looking into programming templates, that should be a trivial task for you.

Comment: since c++: use cout instead printf(), cin instead getchar() (indeed the getchar is not necessary), try catch for new.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I'm migrating from c to c++.

Comment: What's the reason of negative point :(.  I asked only my problem. Do you mean I cannot ask if we are not professional?!

Comment: @remo I've downvoted it because you did not explain what exactly you want. Angew asked you what part you want generic. The question, as it stands isn't clear. If you edit this to improve it, I'll lift the downvote. (On a related note, I'd still like to know what's going to happen about [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811184/how-to-reference-a-pointer-to-pointer-in-c).)

Comment: @remo Also, if all you want is to replace `double` with a generic type, I wonder why you don't give it a try yourself. There are lots of examples for simple function templates on Stackoverflow, and in many other places, including every C++ text book.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. If I study the problem my seld, I will find the old solution of <template class T> ... , but this is not really the optimal solution. The problem is about to improve both my understanding of C++ and coding style. I am editing my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify what you want to be generic, but I'll guess
the type (and maybe the dimensions).  The *usual* way to create
an object (including containers, generic or not) in C++ is to define it
as a class.  Something like:

```
template <typename T, int rows, int columns>
class Matrix
{
    std::vector<T> myData;
public:
    Matrix( T const& init = T() )
        : myData( rows * columns, init )
    {
    }
    T* operator[]( int index )
    {
        return &myData[0] + index * columns;
    }
    T const* operator[]( int index ) const
    {
        return &myData[0] + index * columns;
    }
    //  ...
};
```

If you don't want rows and columns to be compile time constants,
drop them from the template parameters, and add them to the
constructor parameters.  And don't forget to save them.

A somewhat more complex (but still not too difficult) solution
would be to use a proxy class as the return value of
`operator[]`, rather than `T*`.  Another frequent solution is to
override `operator()( int i, int j )` for indexing, and use the
`m( i, j )` syntax, rather than `m[i][j]`.

There is *never* any cause to use array new in C++.  C++ is
*not* C, and you shouldn't try to program it as if it were.

Comment: Would you please introduce me a book I can learn more about the 6 and 7th lines, Matrix( T const& init = T() )
        : myData( rows * columns, init )

Comment: @remo Just about any C++ introductory course should cover it.  Two very good ones: _Programming: Principles and Practice_, by Bjarne Stroustrup (for beginning programmers), and _Accelerated C++_, by Andy Koenig and Barbara Moo (for more advanced programmers).

Comment: Thank you really about the references.